# Not able to get parameter value in twilio function

Tags: twilio

POST
https://webhooks.twilio.com/v1/Accounts/xyz/Flows/xyz

inside

Request
URL
Parameters

AddOns  "{"status":"successful","message":null,"code":null,"results":{"marchex_cleancall":{"request_sid":"abc","status":"successful","message":null,"code":null,"result":{"result":{"recommendation":"PASS","reason":"CleanCall"}}}}}"

CallStatus  "ringing"

I want to get "recommendation":"PASS" value in twilio function how can i get this

Answer (score 0):

Try sending this as a parameter in with you Twilio Function:

```
{{ AddOns | to_json }}
```

Then parse the the object name (it comes in via the events object). So if you set the Function parameter name to addOn, you would access it in the Twilio Function using event.addOn.

You can then use JSON.parse(event.addOn).